# NSX Load Balancer not working with IIS Host header Binding

Tags: iis, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to setup the monitor pages on a VMWare NSX load balancer. The issue is that we are pointing at 2 IIS nodes that are using host header binding and the Service Monitor can't access the monitor pages.

I have configured an F5 load balancer to do the same thing and we were able to specify a send string that contains the host name so it new which website to point at but I can't seem to get the NSX load balancer to send the host name with the request.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: could you give more details on the working and non working URLS used and your iis binding.its not clear whether you need help from IIS or from NSX load balancer.

Comment: Ah sorry, the IIS part is fine, it's the NSX Service Monitor setup that is causing me grief. I don't know how to pass the Host name in the service monitor request to our monitor page.

Comment: You probably have to furnish more details of working and non working URLS and details about your IIS and NSX configuration etc to get any suggestions from anyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I ended up figuring it out myself. There is a way for you to pass the Host header information with the NSX load balancer service monitors.

The NSX Service Monitor config is as follows:

Type: HTTPS 
Expected: 200
Method: GET
URL: /monitor.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:bla.yourcompany.com

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some more research on this and it's covered in the VMware documentation for 6.3, but it applies to previous versions. I also found that adding it via the URL didn't work with a http 1.0 web server.

https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-31772

From slide 15, you can add the host name to the http header adding the following line to the extension box.

header="Host: app1.xyz.com"